# Prevent roles from creating tables in public on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, public

How do you prevent a ROLE from creating TABLES in the PUBLIC schema?

Here is what I have tried:

```
# Logging in as administrator
PGPASSWORD=my_admin_password psql -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX --port XXXXX -d database -U admin_user

# Creating role/user
CREATE ROLE test_role;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database TO test_role;
CREATE USER test_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT test_role TO test_user;

# Removing all permissions on public
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE database FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM test_role;
```

Now let's log in with the test_user:

```
# Logging in as test_user
PGPASSWORD=password psql -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX --port XXXXX -d database -U test_user

# Creating a table 
CREATE TABLE test (id int, name text);
```

Table has been created in public successfully! Wonderful! What is going wrong here? Why can a user will all permissions revoked still create tables?

## Update:

As suggested I have written a few more revokes as the administrator, and it says there is nothing left to revoke. STILL, I can create all the tables I want as **test_user**. I am starting to speculate if it could be some strange behaviour by the **Managed Postgres**, where I do not have access to the **REAL** admin, and it says the owner of **public** is **_rdb_superadmin**. The Postgresql message is not very helpfull, as it doesn't tell me if all permissions have been revoked or not.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command `REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public` only revoked privileges on *existing* tables in that schema, not any privileges on the schema itself.

You need to revoke the privileges on the public schema itself as well:

```
revoke all on schema public from public;
```

It's a bit unclear if you only want to prevent the creation of tables. So maybe you just want

```
revoke create on schema public from public;
```

which would keep the `usage` privilege.

---

In the upcoming Postgres 15, the public role will no longer have the `create` privilege on the schema `public` by default.

Comment: This "public behaviour" in postgres is pretty horrible! Why would you ever allow all users to create whatever they want in the public schema?

Comment: I actually want to remove the public schema entirely as its behaviour is pretty terrible. But as the managed administrator-user does not let me drop it, then I wanted to remove all access to it, but that is also not working.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how this works in RDS - apparently that's quite different than "vanilla" Postgres